# submit form without refresh page using ajax, is STILL refreshing my page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've read and read and looked at examples on SO and tried to find the answer to my question but cant seem to find it but, here's the scenario to my particular problem:

**Main.php**

has a a search form up top, based on search, it posts results on left side of page with help of css.

when you click a result, based on some sql queries it runs, it does a check to see if the person has done a certain event. IF they haven't I want it to post on right side a form to enter some info since if its your first time, with is another php page

Main.php

Search form
-----------------------------------------------------
Results posted...| Tabset.php w/ another 
...........................| form for first time users
...........................|
...........................|
...........................|
...........................|

Apologies for the crude ASCIIish type art, just trying to give a better visual of whats going on.

**Tabset.php**

So in the tabset php page I have the following code:

```
    <div id="main_form">
        <h3>Please enter the following:</h3>
        <FORM id="form1" METHOD="POST">
            <INPUT TYPE = "text" id = "someVAR1"  placeholder="someVAR1"/> / 
            <INPUT TYPE = "text" id = "someVAR2"  placeholder="someVAR2"/>
            <INPUT TYPE = "submit" id = "submit" VALUE = "ok"/>
        </FORM>
    </div>
    <?php

    if($_POST)
    {
        $someVAR1=$_POST['someVAR1'];
        $someVAR2=$_POST['someVAR2'];
    }
```

**refreshform.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var someVAR1= $("#someVAR1").val();
    var someVAR1= $("#someVAR2").val();

    if(someVAR1=='' || someVAR2=='')
    {
      alert("Some Fields are Blank....!!! Please enter something!!!");
    }
    else
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Tabset.php",
        success: function(){
          $('#form1').fadeOut(200).hide();
          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
          $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
          $('#form1')[0].reset();
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

When I click the submit button, its not catching that the fields are empty AND its still refreshing my main.php page

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

I also tried this for my JS as well, with the same results:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var someVAR1= $("#someVAR1").val();
    var someVAR2= $("#someVAR2").val();
    //alert(sBP);

    if(someVAR1==''|| someVAR2==''){
      alert("Some Fields are Blank....!!! Please enter something!!!");    
    }
    else{
      alert("Resetting data now...");
      $('#form')[0].reset(); //To reset form fields

     }
  });
});
```

Comment: I would first suspect a JavaScript error. Please use tools in your browsers console to capture the error.

Comment: have you tried $( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) { instead of $("#submit").click ?

Comment: Do you have included the JQuery library? :]

Comment: You have `someVAR1` defined twice by the way.

Comment: oops, heh thnx on the somevar1, corrected it.

Comment: Twisty, I checked for JS error, it didnt post any as I went thru the motions and clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `someVAR1` defined twice. Better to use `===`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3o9bjhyg/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var someVAR1 = $("#someVAR1").val();
        var someVAR2 = $("#someVAR2").val();

        if (someVAR1 === '' || someVAR2 === '') {
            alert("Some Fields are Blank....!!! Please enter something!!!");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Tabset.php",
                success: function () {
                    $('#form1').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('#form1')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: My tests worked. I hope it is working for you. If this answered your question, I hope you will mark it.

Comment: You mean in your PHP? You never setup the `data` in your AJAX, so no data is being posted to the PHP. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I assume my php...

cus I slimmed it down to just give me AN alert but nothing:



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").submit(function(e) {
    alert("Some Fields are Blank....!!! Please enter your BP!!!");

   });
});

Comment: code works like a charm, its just something else on my portal is doing some kind of override that is preventing this lil section of code to behave as intended, thank you for your help Twisty.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem with the reload is when you are pressing on a submit typed button the submit event was triggered and not click
Please try:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var someVAR1= $("#someVAR1").val();
    var someVAR1= $("#someVAR2").val();

    if(someVAR1=='' || someVAR2=='')
    {
      alert("Some Fields are Blank....!!! Please enter something!!!");
    }
    else
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Tabset.php",
        success: function(){
          $('#form1').fadeOut(200).hide();
          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
          $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
          $('#form1')[0].reset();
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```